# Parsing an XML string to XML and extracting node value in XSLT

Tags: xslt, msxml

I've been trying to parse an XML string to XML and extract the needed values using `msxsl:node-set` function in XSLT. Given below is the XSLT code

```
<xsl:template name="parseXML">
    <xsl:param name="xmlString"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($xmlString)/*"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="parsedXML">
        <xsl:call-template name="parseXML">
          <xsl:with-param name="xmlString" select="result/XML"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
    <element1><xsl:value-of select="$parsedXML"/></element1>
  </xsl:template>
```

I ran the XSLT on the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result name="HostIntegrationRequest" id="0071" status="0">
  <XML>
    <![CDATA[<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:taco.097.001.90"><GrpHdr><MsgId>20230825066</MsgId></GrpHdr></Document>]]></XML>
  <RefId><![CDATA[4]]></RefId>
</result>
```

But the result XML is returning an empty value, I'm unable to see even the parsedXML value.

Some help to solve this issue is appreciated. If I want to select MsgId can I do

`<element1><xsl:value-of select="$parsedXML/Document/GrpHdr/MsgId"/></element1>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node-set() function cannot be used to unescape a string into a proper XML. In XSLT 1.0 you would need to do first:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:value-of select="XML" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then apply another transformation to the resulting file (which in your example would produce an error because `GrpHdr` does not have an ending tag).

Alternatively you could try and parse out the data using string manipulations - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(XML, '&lt;MsgId>'), '&lt;/MsgId>')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>20230825066</result>
```

However, this is not truly parsing the XML and can easily fail if the lexical representation of the XML varies.

In XSLT 3.0 you can use the `parse-xml()` function to parse the escaped string as XML.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I if go the route of the first discussed option i.e. generating a file, how would that work? Should I save the output as XML file and parse it again using another XSLT?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `disable-output-escaping` works only when the output is serialized (and you're using a processor that supports it).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, with MSXML, you can also implement your own `parseXml` function as an extension. With the classic, COM based MSXML (supported versions are MSXML 3 and 6, I think) you can do that with JScript; with the .NET based XslCompiledTransform you can do that by calling into the .NET platform and constructing an XPathDocument from the string you pass in in .NET languages like C# or VB.NET.

For JScript with MSXML 6:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xmlDoc.load('embedded-xml-sample1.xml');

var xsltDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0');
xsltDoc.load('parseXmlExample1.xsl');

var xsltTemplate = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0');
xsltTemplate.stylesheet = xsltDoc;

var xsltProcessor = xsltTemplate.createProcessor();

xsltProcessor.addObject({ "parseXml": function(xml) { var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0'); doc.loadXML(xml); return doc; }}, 'http://example.com/mf');

xsltProcessor.input = xmlDoc;

xsltProcessor.transform();

WScript.Echo(xsltProcessor.output);
```

For .NET with XslCompiledTransform:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

XslCompiledTransform xsltProcessor = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsltProcessor.Load("parseXmlExample1.xsl");

var xsltArguments = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArguments.AddExtensionObject("http://example.com/mf", new XsltExtensions());

xsltProcessor.Transform("embedded-xml-sample1.xml", xsltArguments, Console.Out);

public class XsltExtensions
{
    public static XPathNavigator parseXml(string xml)
    {
        var doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
        return doc.CreateNavigator();
    }
}
```

XSLT for both (in this case solely demonstrating that the extension function parses the XML into a node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf">
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="XML">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:parseXml(string())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a Gist with examples for XslCompiledTransform and MSXML 6: https://gist.github.com/martin-honnen/c5070070d12ac4ba5c72d39afbdae65d